# define correct values for clip in geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

let us suppose we have following  code :

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from geodatasets import get_path
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "City": ["Tbilisi", "Batumi", "Kutaisi", "Rustavi"],
        "Country": ["Georgia", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Georgia"],
        "Latitude": [41.7225, 41.6458, 42.2500, 41.5472],
        "Longitude": [44.7925, 41.6417,42.7000, 45.0111]
    }
)
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude), crs="EPSG:4326"
)
world = geopandas.read_file(get_path("naturalearth.land"))
# print(world.)
# We restrict to Georgia
ax = world.clip([-90, -55, -25, 15]).plot(color="white", edgecolor="black")
# We can now plot our ``GeoDataFrame``.
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color="red")

plt.show()
```

i have taken  exact coordinates from given website :

```
https://simplemaps.com/data/ge-cities
```

but result what i am getting  is this :
[image]

it is because we have following clip :

```
ax = world.clip([-90, -55, -25, 15]).plot(color="white", edgecolor="black")
```

based on figure   got, could you please tell me what values for clip i should take? i tried following  `[0,40,20,40]`, but it returns error of empty rectangle or something like this, please  give me correct direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clip coordinates for the world land map are completely different from the coordinates from the cities...

I guessed some coordinates based on the cities and then the result looks better...

Changed script:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from geodatasets import get_path

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "City": ["Tbilisi", "Batumi", "Kutaisi", "Rustavi"],
        "Country": ["Georgia", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Georgia"],
        "Latitude": [41.7225, 41.6458, 42.2500, 41.5472],
        "Longitude": [44.7925, 41.6417, 42.7000, 45.0111],
    }
)
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude), crs="EPSG:4326"
)

world = geopandas.read_file(get_path("naturalearth.land"))
# print(world.)
# We restrict to Georgia
ax = world.clip([40, 40, 50, 45.0]).plot(color="white", edgecolor="black")
# We can now plot our ``GeoDataFrame``.
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color="red")

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]